# Using Laravel contracts in Application/Domain layers

Tags: laravel, design-patterns, interface, port, clean-architecture

I'm building application at top of the Laravel. In my `Domain` layer I have services. One of these needs to send an EMail. Laravel has `Illuminate\Mail` package for these purposes.

But `Mailer` contract depends on `\Illuminate\Mail\PendingMail` class.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Contracts/Mail/Mailer.php

Does it mean I need to write my own interface (port) for my `Domain` layer to fully decouple my application from framework?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm not sure what you are asking. But I'll try to answer anway.

If you use (any) framework functionality directly in your code, you obviously couple your application to the framework. That's the whole point of a framework. It offers you a lot of functionalities that are commonly used throughout different types of applications. It can be seen as foundation for an applciation. These functionalities are often made available through interfaces, so that the implementation can be swapped out if necessary. Swapping out the implementation doesn't make your application less coupled to the framework though. It just allows you to use a different kind of implementation; the interface will still be a framework one.

So, the only way to prevent (heavy) coupling with a framework would be to write your own interfaces that abstract all the framework functionalities. You could then have proxy classes that implement these new interfaces and do nothing else than proxying requests to the proper functions of the framework, allowing you to write other proxy classes in future for a different framework.

If you ask me, this sounds like a bad idea though. Because in the end, you are building your own framework based on your own interfaces. So you are using additional custom code which adds no additional functionality, but comes with the added risk of bugs and errors.

Comment: Laravel provides their Contracts as separate _composer_ package. I agree to use them (contracts). For example `Illuminate\Cache`. It satisfies all of my requirements.  Laravel provides realization of these Contracts as _framework_ components.

So I can use Contracts in my own services with Laravel's realization within `Container`. If I will change framework or cache library, I just can register another library (or adapter to this library) with `Cache` contract and do not change any code in my service, because `Cache` contract doesn't depend on Laravel realization. But `Mailer` depends.

Comment: Well, that's true. In this case it might be worth opening an issue in the [laravel/ideas](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues) project suggesting a change of contract. Because I agree with you - the interface should not ask for concrete return types.

Comment: thank for the tip. I have created an issue https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/1456